# Как использовать общий SharedPreference между Unity и Android?

Tags: java, android, unity3d, плагин

Моя основная задача заключается в том чтобы, научить Unity читать значения из SharedPreference, я пробовал следовать [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682977/using-shared-preferences-between-unity-and-native-android-sdk) инструкции, но ничего не работает, возможно я что то не понял. Подскажите, что не так?!

Сначала я сделал плагин из этого кода:

```
package com.yourcompany.productname.activity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;

    public class lib extends Activity {
        public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

        public void setPreferenceString (String prefKey, String prefValue) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(prefKey, prefValue);
            editor.commit();

        }

        public String getPreferenceString (String prefKey) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String playerName = settings.getString(prefKey, "");
            return playerName;
        }
    }
```

Поместил плагин и манифест в Assets/Plugins/Android/libs, затем создал такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Plugin : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        SetPreferenceString("playerName", "John Doe");
    }

    void Update () {
        TextMesh textMesh = GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
        var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.yourcompany.productname.activity.lib");
        textMesh.text = plugin.CallStatic<string> ("getPreferenceString", "playerName");
    }

    AndroidJavaObject AJO = null;

    public void SetPreferenceString (string prefKey, string prefValue) {
        if(AJO == null)
            AJO = new AndroidJavaObject("com.yourcompany.productname.activity.lib", new object[0]);

        AJO.Call("setPreferenceString", new object[] { prefKey, prefValue } );
    }

    public string GetPreferenceString (string prefKey) {
        if(AJO == null)
            AJO = new AndroidJavaObject("com.yourcompany.productname.activity.lib", new object[0]);

        if(AJO == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return AJO.Call<string>("getPreferenceString", new object[] { prefKey } );
    }
}
```

Как я понял должно работать так, вызывается метод SetPreferenceString обращаться к плагину и записывать значение, затем точно так же это значение выводится.

Comment: Проверь сначала, чтобы  java тебе хотя бы константу возвращал, если не вернет, то проблема в  библиотеке/манифесте.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ нет ничего не возвращает, я так же пробывал из другой активность записать настройки, тем же самым "setPreferenceString" в итоге Unity скрипт все равно ничего не смог запросить

Comment: @DeKaNszn у меня проблема с обратным, я не могу из Unity получить значения настроек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Unity необходимо использовать встроенный класс [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). Из его описания:

> On Android data is stored (persisted) on the device. The data is saved
>   in SharedPreferences. C#/JavaScript, Android Java and Native code can
>   all access the PlayerPrefs data. The PlayerPrefs data is physically
>   stored in /data/data/pkg-name/shared_prefs/pkg-name.xml.

Код для Unity:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", "Foobar"); // запись
PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName"); // чтение
```

Код для Java:

```
String sharedPreferenceName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".v2.playerprefs";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String playerName = settings.getString("PlayerName", ""); // чтение

// запись
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("PlayerName", "Foobar");
editor.apply();
```

Comment: context подсвечен красным "Cannot resolve symbol", дописал Context context; и приложение крашится

Comment: @Jonathan я не просто так попросил код того, как вы записываете. здесь абстрактный пример, который требует небольшой корректировки под ваш код

Comment: я просто не совсем понял формулировку "как записываете". Я запускал этот код из под активности наследуемой от PreferenceActivity, просто нажатием кнопки, если вы об этом

Comment: подправил Java код для запуска из любого Activity

Comment: можете подсказать еще одну вещь, почему на стороне Unity данные не обновляются, если я меняю значение  например Foobar1, то в Unity так же отображается Foobar?

Comment: может быть Unity кеширует? так же учтите, что для сохранения настроек в java надо вызвать apply()/commit() - первый для асинхронного, второй для синхронного сохранения

Comment: да похоже что кэширует, ясно учту, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вызываешь callstatic(а функция у тебя не статическая), замени на call

```
textMesh.text = plugin.CallStatic<string> ("getPreferenceString", "playerName");
```

Comment: да точно, но код все равно не работает